# regex capture everything except a word (break at a word not character)

Tags: python, regex

Inputs

```
a = "Miami, FL"
b = "Boston, MA or Miami, FL"
c = "United Kingdom"
```

RegEx

```
loc = re.compile('([^or]+)[,]*[\s]*([A-Z]+)')
locs = loc.findall(b)
```

How can I make it break at `or`? It will break at `o` I know. And `[^(or)]` and `[^\(or\)]` won't work either.

Comment: What do you mean by "break"?

Comment: Add your "Desired Output".

Comment: Would something like `'(?<= or|^)[, ]*([A-Z]+)'` help you? Have no Python and can't test it, so only comment :p

Comment: @Jonny5 yep pipe is life saver here :)

Comment: I dont think you can use words in a character class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
loc = re.compile('(?:^|or)\s*([^,]+),\s([A-Z]+)')
```

Comment: thanks it makes sense. I did not know pipe is allowed in regex. I will improve it for `c`

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you want split string by `or`. Use [`re.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split):

```
>>> b = "Boston, MA or Miami, FL"
>>> re.split(r'\bor\b', b)
['Boston, MA ', ' Miami, FL']
```

---

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?:^|or)\s*([^,]+,?\s[a-z]+)', a, flags=re.I)
['Miami, FL']
>>> re.findall(r'(?:^|or)\s*([^,]+,?\s[a-z]+)', b, flags=re.I)
['Boston, MA', 'Miami, FL']
>>> re.findall(r'(?:^|or)\s*([^,]+,?\s[a-z]+)', c, flags=re.I)
['United Kingdom']
```

Comment: yes split would work but I am interested to do it with regex alone.

Comment: @TalhaAshraf, Do you mean .. with only `re.findall` ?